# Why does my function keep getting errors?

Tags: c, cs50, collatz

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int collatz(int n);
int main(void)
{
    int x = get_int("number: ");
    collatz(x);
    printf("%d", collatz(x));
}

int collatz(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 0;
    else if ((n % 2) == 0)
        return 1 + collatz(n/2);
    else if ((n % 2) == 1)
        return 1 + collatz((n*3) + 1);
}
```

When I run this code, I keep getting the error message

```
collatz.c:20:1: error: control may reach end of non-void function
      [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
}
```

If I change the function to void I get the error message

```
collatz.c:15:9: error: void function 'collatz' should not return a value
      [-Wreturn-type]
        return 0;
```

Am I doing something else incorrectly? The collatz function returns a value but the function does not compile correctly under both void and int.

Comment: How large can an `int` input become before its value eventually becomes `1`? Think about what happens when you enter a large odd number.

Comment: You have called `collatz` *twice* and discard the first result.

Answer (score 7):

Just add an extra branch to make the compiler happy:

```
int collatz(int n)
{
if (n == 1)
    return 0;
else if ((n % 2) == 0)
    return 1 + collatz(n/2);
else if ((n % 2) == 1)
    return 1 + collatz((n*3) + 1);
else
    return -1; // this happen if called with odd negative n.
}
```

Comment: You also could omit the last `else`. But it might improve readability.

Comment: If you weed out the negative value at the start of the function, or before it is even called, then `n % 2` can be performed once only since there are only two possible values, and the `else`s are just clutter since the function already returned.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite `collatz` so that the compiler can see it can't exit without hitting a `return` statement:

```
int collatz(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 0;

    if ((n % 2) == 0)
        return 1 + collatz(n/2);

    return 1 + collatz((n*3) + 1);
}
```

Comment: Consider negative value for n

Answer (score 0):

The warning message clearly explains why compiler is throwing it.

```
error: control may reach end of non-void function
```

This means it is not guaranteed that function will return something. Your function's return type is `int` so it needs to return an `int`. Your `if-else` conditions are not exhaustive (consider negative numbers) and so the control flow may reach the end of the function without returning anything.

> If I change the function to void I get the error message
>
> ```
> collatz.c:15:9: error: void function 'collatz' should not return a value
>   [-Wreturn-type]
>     return 0;
> ```

If you change the function return type to void, you cannot return an int from it. Hence this message.

As others have already suggested you need to rewrite the function in such a way that compiler is sure about hitting some `return` statement.

Also Weather Vane has pointed out some more serious mistakes in your code. Please pay attention to them.